# Importing Csv file using oledb - not reading "1.2.3.4" value

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

I want import csv file to database using oledb connectivity into c#. My csv file have 9 columns into this one column is "Version Number" which have value "1.2.3.4", when I load the csv file data into datatable it convert this value to "1.234". I want "1.2.3.4" value to save into database. I tried to change column datatype to Text into csv but still it convert. Need suggestion on this, how can I solve this problem.

```
 OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionString.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        if (extension == ".csv")
        {
            connectionString["Extended Properties"] = "text;HDR=Yes;";
            connectionString.DataSource = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
            tableName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        }
        else
            if (extension == ".xls")
            {
                connectionString["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
                connectionString.DataSource = fileName;
            }
            else
                if (extension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
                    connectionString.DataSource = fileName;
                }
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [{1}]", fileName), 
                   connectionString.ToString());
DataTable dtbCSV = new DataTable();
oleda.Fill(dtbCSV);
```

Csv File Data :

```
Name                    Policy Category VersionName        ReleaseDate  Description                      DownloadType   Version     FileUrl
What's_New_Release_8.1  Trial       What's_New_Release_8.1  9/1/2016    This is the Description for Downloads   Sku      1.1        https://google.com/image/temp.png
Release 7 0 What's New  Trial       Release 7 0 What's New  10/5/2016   This is the Description for Downloads   Sku      1.23.41.2  http://google.com/image/temp.png
```

Schema.ini File:

```
[6770aedf-e6b7-44de-afbf-8380f5c450ca.csv] 
 ColNameHeader=True 
 Format=CSVDelimited 
 Col1=Name Text Width 500 
 Col2=Policy Text Width 1000
 Col3=Category Text Width 1000 
 Col4=VersionName Text Width 1000
 Col5=ReleaseDate DateTime
 Col6=Description Text Width 1000
 Col7=DownloadType Text Width 1000
 Col8=Version DateTime
 Col9=FileUrl Text Width 1000
```

This is my schema.ini and it is in the temp folder where I save my csv files

Thanks in Advance,
Sandy

Comment: Please provide a code sample

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample of your csv file

Comment: From jaber borzouei:  can you send part of csv file or what character seperator in csv file ?

Comment: The OLEDB provider has to guess each field's type. This is typically done by reading the first 50 rows, although this can be changed. If the first 50 rows only contain numeric data, the provider will parse the column as a decimal. You can change the property in the connection string although a far better solution would be to use a CSV library like CSVHelper, which doesn't need any drivers

Comment: What you've added doesn't look at all as a CSV. What is the separator? tabs?

Comment: Don't. I hate to say it, but the OleDB driver for CSV files it so mind-numbingly broken that if you go get it to work, it will be by accident. I spent a lot of time researching this topic and just found one problem after another.

Comment: .NET has a built-in CSV parser that works really well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonathanAllen this is just a VB.NET convenience class that reads individual lines as string fields. You still have to parse each individual entry, even if you already know the file's schema. The OLEDB provider can infer the schema or use a `schema.ini` file. CSVHelper and purpose-built libraries though go even farther and directly map to objects, or even support LINQ

Comment: IMHO it is stupid to use OleDb to read a plane text csv file. In this case, you could just store the content of the csv file via __System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()__ in a array of strings. this can be splittetd then by a delimiter like ; or ,

Comment: Once again: Your file is NOT csv delimited. And ColNameHeader must be FALSE in order to Column definitions to be used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The fact that it is inside the VB namespace doesn't matter in the slightest. There is nothing VB specific about its functionality and I often use it from C#. It is ok to prefer CSVHelper, but don't dismiss `TextFieldParser` just because you don't like the namespace it happens to be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,first of all I will assume your csv file is tab delimited. 
What you need is to specify the column types for OleDb to correctly parse it. The best way I think is using a `schema.ini` file, that must be in the same path that your csv file is in. This is a sample of how it should look:

```
[test.csv]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=false
MaxScanRows=0
Col1=Name Text
Col2=Policy Text
Col3=VersionName Text
Col4=ReleaseDate Text
Col5=Description Text
Col6=DownloadType Text
Col7=Version Text
Col8=FileUrl Text
```

As you see, in the first line you must specify your csv file name. Then I set the delimiter to tabs. After that, I deactivate that the first line is the headers line (this would lead you to delete the first line in your csv). An after that, you must define all your columns with the intended type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Describe your problem. We can't help you if you don't @Sandy

Comment: The problem is I have one columns name as "Version" which have values like "1.2.3","4.2","2.5.6.4". When I try to import csv it convert this values to "1.23","4.2","2.564" which mean it takes only one dot others it removes when loading data from csv into datatable or datareader.

Comment: I have tried the schema.ini file I posted and it works fine. Either your csv file is not tab delimited, or the schema.ini file is not in the same path of your csv file, or you have not changed the file name in the first line of the schema.ini

Comment: @Sandy post what you tried in the question, not the comments.

Comment: @Sandy that's not the file Pikoh posted. You have a tab-delimited file, yet you entered `Format=CSVDelimited`. It should be `Format=TabDelimited`. Try with Pikoh's file first before making modifications

Comment: @Sandy also note that you need to specify the `DateTimeFormat` option if you want to translate text directly to dates. Is `9/1/2016` January 9 or September 1?

Comment: http://aspdotnetcodes.com/importing_csv_database_schema.ini.aspx I followed steps given in this link

Comment: @Sandy you followed all the steps except the ones I told you it seems...

Comment: Yeah @Pikoh I done the changes you told me and debug code still it is giving me the same string

Comment: Hi @Pikoh, it is working but if I use TabDeliminator it takes all column values into one column. What should I use then?

Comment: @Sandy it depends on your csv file. What is the delimitator between the fields? a TAB, a comma?

Comment: If the fields are comma-separated,you should use `Format=CSVDelimited`.But then,the example data you provided to us was not correct  :) @Sandy

Answer (score 0):

@Pikoh already explained how to use a `schema.ini` file to control who the driver treats each field.

Another option is to use a library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which reads *and* maps CSV data directly to objects, eg:

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
IEnumerable<MyClass> records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();
```

`GetRecords` returns an IEnumerable which means that rows are loaded lazily *and* you can use LINQ to filter them or load specific fields only:

```
var records = from record in csv.GetRecords<MyClass>()
              where record.ReleseDate > new DateTime(2016,09,01)
              select new {record.Name};
```

Fields can be mapped automatically, or you can specify your own mapping with a fluent interface. The mapping class also allows you to specify localization options, eg to handle `MM/DD/YYYY` vs `DD/MM/YYYY`formats:

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Description ).Index( 0 )
                           .TypeConverterOption( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
        Map( m => m.TimeStamp ).Index( 1 )
                          .TypeConverterOption( DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal );
        Map( m => m.Cost ).Index( 2 )
                          .TypeConverterOption( NumberStyles.Currency );
        Map( m => m.CurrencyFormat ).Index( 3 )
                          .TypeConverterOption( "C" );
        Map( m => m.BooleanValue ).Index( 4 )
                          .TypeConverterOption( true, "sure" )
                          .TypeConverterOption( false, "nope" );
    }
}
```

Finally, you avoid the hassle of installing the correct OLEDB driver (x86 or x64).

Comment: csvHelper is different package, I can't change the existing import code. Can give me the solution with Oledb

Comment: @Pikoh already posted that. CsvHelper is an alternative that doesn't require adding a new driver, that may not even work if you mix x64 and x86 binaries